# Como verificar se um site esta registrado?

Tags: php, aplicação-web

Como posso verificar se um determinado domínio (DNS) está disponível para registro? Basicamente o que preciso é fazer uma consulta WHOIS. Irei fazer essa consulta em PHP.

Comment: Tente editar a sua pergunta a modo de deixar claro que você quer implementar no seu site um campo que verifica a disponibilidade de registro de um site, e se possivel a linguagem que prefere para verificar isto. Pois no modo como está, dá a entender que você está procurando um site para verificar se dá para você registrar um dominio.

Comment: Verificar se está registrado onde (só no Brasil, etc)? Tem algum motivo especial pra vc reconstruir esse tipo de serviço e não usar o(s) serviço(s) existente(s) (como o https://registro.br/cgi-bin/whois/)?

Comment: Pra ter uma pesquisa segura, vai precisar consultar toda essa listinha de registrars aqui: https://www.internic.net/alpha.html - Do jeito que está, a pergunta é "ampla demais" no meu ver. Sugeriria restringir o foco do problema.

Comment: Uma solução seria você eleger os TLDs que precisa de fato consultar.

Comment: Sinceramente, ate agora nao entendi o pq dos votos negativos, mas cada um vota como queira. E se perceber posso nao ter usado as palavras corretas, mas o que eu precisava era essa tal da consulta WHOIS. Obrigado a todos que ajudaram.

Comment: Eu não votei negativo, mas entendo que o problema da pergunta é ser ampla demais. Não tem um "whois" universal para este tipo de consulta. Tinha quando era tudo registrado num lugar só. Hoje a coisa mudou, vide meus comentários acima.Ajudaria se você definisse ao menos o escopo da pesquisa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Talvez o que você necessita é uma consulta WHOIS.

Existe uma biblioteca chamada https://github.com/regru/php-whois que utiliza uma série de serviços pra consulta https://github.com/regru/php-whois/blob/master/src/Phois/Whois/whois.servers.json

Exemplo de uso:

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$sld = 'dominio.com.br';//Dominio que quer verificar

$domain = new Phois\Whois\Whois($sld);

if ($domain->isAvailable()) {
    echo 'Domínio disponível';
} else {
    echo 'Domínio indisponível';
}
```

Apesar de não mencionado no repositório, ele requer composer.

Todavia se não estiver usando composer, no caso deste repositório espefico você pode tentar baixar o https://github.com/regru/php-whois/archive/master.zip e copiar a pasta `src` pro seu projeto então fazer a chamada da classe assim:

```
<?php
require_once 'src/Phois/Whois/Whois.php';

$sld = 'dominio.com.br';//Dominio que quer verificar

$domain = new Phois\Whois\Whois($sld);

if ($domain->isAvailable()) {
    echo 'Domínio disponível';
} else {
    echo 'Domínio indisponível';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Você está se referindo a ter o dominio registrado em orgãos competentes como o registro.br ou ao site estar já publicado?

Se for por questões de registro de dominio, o comando "whois" faz isso, apresentando (se disponíveis) informações sobre o dono do domínio, data de registro, expiração, etc...

Já para verificar se o site está publicado e online, há serviços como o [Down For Everyone Or Just Me](http://isup.me/) que mostram o status atual do site, se está online ou offline.

Comment: Estou me referindo em o usuário digitar um endereço qualquer e saber se é um domínio livre para ele poder registrar ou não. Mas preciso criar o meu próprio buscador e não ir em um outro site e saber entendeu?

Comment: Pode-se então usar o comando "whois" como dito anteriomente:

$ whois stackoverflow.com
[Consulta whois.verisign-grs.com]
[Redirecionado para whois.name.com]
[Consulta whois.name.com]
[whois.name.com]
Domain Name: STACKOVERFLOW.COM 
Registry Domain ID: 108907621_DOMAIN_COM-VRSN 
Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.name.com 
Registrar URL: http://www.name.com 
Updated Date: 2015-11-26T17:58:30Z 
Creation Date: 2003-12-26T19:18:07Z 

Porém, se consultarmos o dominio stackoverflow.net.br


[whois.registro.br]

%  2016-03-23 10:48:04 (BRT -03:00)

% No match for domain "stackoverflow.net.br"

[/pre]

Comment: Desculpe, pressionei "Enter" acidentalmente antes enquanto editava a resposta. o comando "whois" é diponivel nativamente na maioria das distribuições Linux, quanto ao Windows, não tenho certeza.

link=http://www.uolhost.uol.com.br/faq/dominios/o-que-e-whois.html#rmcl

Comment: Não testei, mas este é o primeiro resultado de uma busca feita no Google pelo termo "php whois":https://github.com/regru/php-whois - há diversos outros exemplos disponpiveis.