# registrar dominio pelo site

Tags: php

Oi, gostaria de integrar com registro.br paro usuario escolher um diminio e mostrar se está disponivel ou não e caso esteja disponivel ele pudesse se cadastrar sem acessar o registro.br, alguem sabe fazer isso?

Comment: O registro.br tem a API para EPP, só não é aberta pra uso imediato. Você precisa homologar sua aplicação e fazer um "adiantamento" de créditos em torno de uns 4000 reais (nao sei se o valor ainda é esse, faz mais de ano que não consulto).

Comment: @Bacco boa, não sabia. http://registro.br/tecnologia/provedor-hospedagem.html?secao=epp

Comment: Update: para liberação do sistema você tem que fazer um adiantamento de 100 registros, ou seja, R$2700, que ficarão como crédito para uso no sistema. (grato @Randrade por ter apontado o valor correto)

Answer (score 4):

É possivel consultar usando WHOIS e cadastrar/controlar usando [EPP](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5730.txt). Eu cheguei a adicionar uma  resposta que fiz de como consultar:

- [Como verificar se um site esta registrado?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/120172/3635)

<s>Na verdade quando você faz um registro no registro.br ou outros sites de serviço semelhante na verdade o que eles geram é um TICKET de serviço deles, o processo então provavelmente ocorre em parte manualmente, já que eles detém o `.br` parte só é automatizada justamente por eles proprietários.</s>

O que quero dizer com isso, é que todos como `.net.br`, `.com.br`, `.org.br` na verdade pertencem aos detentores do `.br` e quando contratamos é um uso nosso dentro do contrato deles, assim como `.com`, `.org`, `.co` devem pertencer a órgãos diferentes.

A única maneira de cadastrar algo no registro será se eles tivessem uma API, então quando a pessoa fizesse o cadastro iria gerar um TICKET e o resto do processo que provavelmente é em parte manual seria por conta deles (registro.br).

---

Lendo o site deles encontrei isto http://registro.br/tecnologia/provedor-hospedagem.html (não sei se atenderá a tudo)

## Consulta

O serviço está disponível em `whois.registro.br`, porta `43` em `UDP`. É possível utilizar este serviço de 3 formas:

- Fazer consultas através do site do Registro.br

  O Serviço de Disponibilidade de Domínios está publicado na nossa página inicial.
- Utilizar um dos clientes-exemplo (pode lhe ser útil para estudar como funciona)

  O Registro.br disponibiliza clientes-exemplo totalmente funcionais escritos nas linguagens Python, Perl, PHP e Java. O download pode ser feito em ftp://ftp.registro.br/pub/isavail/
- Utilizar implementação própria (provavelmente é o que procura)

  O usuário com conhecimentos técnicos ainda tem a opção de implementar seu próprio cliente seguindo as especificações do protocolo descritas no documento [Protocolo-ISAVAILv1.txt](http://registro.br/tecnologia/Protocolo-ISAVAILv1.txt).

Eu não testei, desconheço limitações, mas me parece que irá atender a tudo que deseja, conforme o site são estas as funcionalidades, além de informar se o domínio consultado está disponível para registro, o Serviço de Disponibilidade de Domínios ainda fornece informações adicionais como, por exemplo, a delegação de domínios já registrados, o motivo pelo qual um determinado domínio consultado não pode ser registrado, tickets concorrentes ou ainda datas referentes ao processo de liberação, quando for o caso.

## Controle

Conforme o @Bacco citou existe o http://registro.br/tecnologia/provedor-hospedagem.html?secao=epp

O protocolo EPP é um padrão do IETF que permite que provedores de serviço executem operações de provisionamento em objetos de um repositório central. Sua principal aplicação é a automatização do registro e manutenção de domínios.

O acesso ao serviço EPP do .br é permitido apenas aos provedores aprovados num processo de homologação técnica. Este processo é composto de uma sequência de comandos minimamente suficiente para cobrir as principais operações do protocolo EPP.

O cliente é escrito em C++ http://registro.br/tecnologia/provedor-hospedagem.html?secao=epp&item=libepp-nicbr

Uma vez definida a forma de integração com os sistemas do Registro.br, é necessário solicitar o cadastro do provedor no ambiente de homologação e testes.

1. Definição da forma de integração dos sistemas do provedor com o serviço EPP do .br
   Além da biblioteca cliente libepp-nicbr, desenvolvida pelo Registro.br em C++, outras implementações do protocolo EPP podem ser utilizadas.

   Como EPP é um protocolo padrão, com interface XML sobre transporte TCP com TLS, qualquer linguagem capaz de gerar e processar XML sobre TLS pode ser utilizada para integração dos sistemas do provedor com o Registro.br, bastando que a implementação cliente siga as recomendações listadas na seção Referências EPP.

   Durante o desenvolvimento da integração dos sistemas, é importante observar com cuidado as Políticas e restrições ao serviço EPP do .br para o correto funcionamento do sistema.
2. Acesso ao ambiente de homologação e testes
   Uma vez definida a forma de integração com os sistemas do Registro.br, é necessário solicitar o cadastro do provedor no ambiente de homologação e testes.

   Esta solicitação deve ser feita com o envio do Formulário de Homologação preenchido para epp-suporte@registro.br. Observe que o item 2 do formulário deve ser preenchido com um código de usuário cadastrado no próprio ambiente de homologação. Seu usuário no site em produção do Registro.br não pode ser utilizado no ambiente de testes.

   Os dados de acesso ao serviço EPP serão enviados por e-mail assim que o cadastro do provedor for concretizado.
3. Aprovação no procedimento de homologação
   Uma vez apto a interoperar com o Registro.br via EPP, o provedor deve demonstrar sua total compreensão do protocolo e do sistema de registro de domínios brasileiro. Para tal é necessário executar com perfeição o Procedimento de Homologação de Provedores de Serviços EPP no Registro.br.

   Este procedimento deve ser realizado no intervalo máximo de 1 hora. Ao terminar, o provedor deve enviar um e-mail para epp-suporte@registro.br informando o endereço IP utilizado na conexão, o nome do provedor e os horários de início e fim do procedimento. O Registro.br responderá em aproximadamente 48hs.
4. Assinatura de contrato
   Após confirmada a homologação, o provedor deverá enviar o Formulário do Contrato preenchido para epp@registro.br, para que possamos elaborar o contrato.

   A minuta do contrato bem como instruções para encaminhamento do processo serão enviados por e-mail para providências do provedor.
5. Depósito inicial
   Após a confirmação da efetivação do contrato, o Registro.br entrará em contato por e-mail para solicitar que seja feito o depósito inicial. Este depósito deve ser realizado seguindo o Procedimento de Crédito para Provedores de Serviços EPP. O valor será automaticamente convertido em créditos para utilização no registro e manutenção de domínios.

   Uma vez efetivado o crédito inicial o provedor receberá, enfim, uma conta EPP no sistema de produção do Registro.br.
6. Solicitação do certificado SSL

   O acesso ao servidor EPP de produção exige o uso de um certificado SSL de uso exclusivo do provedor, o qual é emitido pelo NIC.br somente após o cadastro da conta EPP no sistema. Para obter este certificado, siga as instruções descritas em Solicitando um certificado SSL.

### A maneira alternativa

Em alguns casos fazer todo o processo do EPP pode ser inviável em alguns casos,  como alternativa você poderia criar um dashboard para usuários semelhante ao do registro.br para registrar dominios, mas eles gerariam TICKETs para você e o processo de atualização até conclusão do ticket seria manual da parte do prestador do serviço, no caso você ou sua empresa, algumas empresas começam assim, "revendendo" serviços existentes e poderia implementar o sistema acima citado para checar se já esta ativado e semi-automatizar algumas coisas.

Comment: boa @Guilherme Nascimento +1

Answer (score 2):

O Registro.br dispõe sim de APIs, uma chamada isavail e uma chamada EPP. 
A API isavail permite apenas verificar a disponibilidade de um domínio, mas não exige cadastro e portanto mais ágil de implementar:
http://registro.br/tecnologia/provedor-hospedagem.html?secao=disponibilidade

Já a interface EPP permite checar disponibilidade e fazer novos registros, mas é necessário assinar um contrato com o Registro.br após demonstrar capacidade técnica. O link é
http://registro.br/tecnologia/provedor-hospedagem.html?secao=epp

O processo EPP é 100% automatizado para domínios que não requerem envio prévio de documentação, então os mais comuns como com.br e net.br podem ser registrados com automação total. Já por exemplo gov.br e mil.br precisam de autorização de órgãos específicos.