# como colocar um verificador de dominio em php?

Tags: php

Bom, eu estou com um site bem desenvolvido, porém, eu quero colocar uma página para verificar se o domínio já está registrado sim ou não, pesquisei muito antes de chegar aqui, então nenhuma funcionou, o meu código em html está desta forma

```
                        <div class="" id="chND_Verificar">
                             <label class=" control-label label_defaults" for="chND_Login" id="chND_Verificar">                   
                             </label>
                             <div class="">
                               <input type="text" placeholder="Digite o seu domínio" autocomplete="off" autofocus class="autofocus-caret-beginning" required ng-model="input.domain" name="domain" id="cart_domain_search_domain" ng-disabled="loading">
                             </div>
                          </div>                                                                                   
                             <div id="f1_upload_process" class="form-group" style="display:none;">
                                <label class=" control-label label_defaults"></label>
                                <img src="http://www.fdsacesse.com/code/media/images/loader.svg" width="32" />
                             </div>
                             <div class="form-group">
                                <label class=" control-label label_defaults"></label>
                                <input class="submit" type="submit" value="CONSULTAR" ng-disabled="searchForm.domain.$error.pattern || loading">
                             </div>
```

porém gostaria de saber, como eu poderei prossegui?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar `checkdnsrr` ou `gethostbyname`:

Documentação:

http://www.php.net/checkdnsrr

http://www.php.net/gethostbyname

Exemplo de `checkdnsrr`:

```
<?php
 if ( checkdnsrr('example.com.', 'ANY') ) {
  echo "DNS Record found";
 }
 else {
  echo "NO DNS Record found";
 }
?>
```

Exemplo de `gethostbyname`:

```
<?php
 $domain = 'example.com';
 if ( gethostbyname($domain) != $domain ) {
  echo "DNS Record found";
 }
 else {
  echo "NO DNS Record found";
 }
?>
```

fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8693519/7437072

Ou como citou o Guilherme Nascimento [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/120172/21112) .

Talvez o que você necessita é uma consulta WHOIS.

Existe uma biblioteca chamada https://github.com/regru/php-whois que utiliza uma série de serviços pra consulta https://github.com/regru/php-whois/blob/master/src/Phois/Whois/whois.servers.json

Exemplo de uso:

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$sld = 'dominio.com.br';//Dominio que quer verificar

$domain = new Phois\Whois\Whois($sld);

if ($domain->isAvailable()) {
    echo 'Domínio disponível';
} else {
    echo 'Domínio indisponível';
}
```

Comment: Neste caso o WHOIS me permite verificar se o domínio que o cliente quer para o site dele está disponível sim ou não igual a esta forma [link](https://www.hostinger.com.br/registro-de-dominio) ?

Comment: Sim, só utilizar a biblioteca como mostrado no exemplo